# AudioManager.setCommunicationDevice to TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER not working

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-12

I am attempting to implement a Loud Speaker / Earpiece switch in Android 12 using the new `AudioManager.setCommunicationDevice` in place of the deprecated `AudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn`.

The result of the set call is true, but the device does not appear to update (both functionally and by checking `AudioManager.getCommunicationDevice` before and after).

The application is selected as the default Phone package, AudioManager mode is set to `AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL` and the manifest includes

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />`

Below is a code snippet which shows the effect of trying to just set loud speaker during an active call.

```
    AudioDeviceInfo loudSpeakerAudioDevice = null;
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);

    List<AudioDeviceInfo> audioDevices = audioManager.getAvailableCommunicationDevices();
    for (AudioDeviceInfo audioDevice : audioDevices)
    {
        if (audioDevice.getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER)
        {
            loudSpeakerAudioDevice = audioDevice;
        }
    }

    Log.i("Demo", "Current AudioDevice = " + audioManager.getCommunicationDevice().toString());
    if (audioManager.getCommunicationDevice().getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_EARPIECE)
    {
        Log.i("Demo", "Setting to loudSpeakerAudioDevice = " + loudSpeakerAudioDevice.toString());
        if (audioManager.setCommunicationDevice(loudSpeakerAudioDevice) == false)
        {
            Log.e("Demo", "Failed to set audio device");
        }
        Log.i("Demo", "New AudioDevice = " + audioManager.getCommunicationDevice().toString());
    }
```

The output of this shows the device ID is the same before and after the set (21).

```
2022-07-27 10:30:01.465 27907-27907/? I/Demo: Current AudioDevice = android.media.AudioDeviceInfo@21
2022-07-27 10:30:01.501 27907-27907/? I/Demo: Setting to loudSpeakerAudioDevice = android.media.AudioDeviceInfo@22
2022-07-27 10:30:01.518 27907-27907/? I/Demo: New AudioDevice = android.media.AudioDeviceInfo@21
```

Comment: Hey! I ran the same code as yours and everything worked fine although I wasn't making a real call. Could you try to run this code without the actual phone call and check if the device has been changed accordingly?

Comment: Thanks @PineapplePie, I can confirm the same behaviour here.  The Audio Device correctly updates outside of a call but fails during one.  The API documentation indicates if multiple applications are trying to modify the audio device, the last one to request ```MODE_IN_CALL``` takes precedence so as far as I can see this should work...

Comment: And what about this part from the docs? Have you tried to provide this permission? 


>Note that MODE_IN_CALL can only be selected by the main telephony application with permission Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE.

Comment: Any solution so far ? I have the same problem, nothing works during the call , even with MODE_IN_CALL and Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: I too noticed that API function setCommunicationDevice to AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER device does not work if audio mode is MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION.  It does work if mode is NORMAL.  Turning off speakerphone using clearCommunicationDevice does work in both modes.  Has anyone created an issue to Google bugs?

Answer (score 0):

thats not the one and only api for audio routing, thanks Google...

for such connections (calls, voip) you should implement [Telecom framework](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/telecom) and implement own [`Connection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Connection) class. When your connnections are created/registered by system (`ConnectionService` impl) then you can change audio sink with [`setAudioRoute`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Connection#setAudioRoute(int)) (which just got deprecated and there is smth new, I've just noticed...)